# how to move to next record to add to the List, when current record gets error/not valid in c#

Tags: asp.net, linq, c#-3.0

I'm reading excel file, where i have nth number of records.

I will move these record to the List in c#.

my question is:
How to move to next record when current record gets an error or not valid to add to the list, using C#.

Can any one plz help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the code you currently work with and ask the specific question you face. Code writing service isn't what this community for.

Answer (score 0):

It's all in how you filter it.
You could put a function in the middle of the loop that catches exceptions so they won't stop your load.

You could also pick up everything as a string and convert it after you test its validity.

Depending on how the whole range is formatted, you may be able to test it for a range of a certain "type".

Here is a very simplistic example of something like that where I pull integers out of a list of objects:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO_46192609_CS
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         List<Object> lst_obj = new List<object>
         {
            "fred", -1, int.Parse("7"), "joe", "bill", 5.ToString() 
         };

         List<int> lst_int = lst_obj.OfType<int>().ToList();
      }
   }
}
```